# Need to remove sentences containing "?" in a text file

Tags: python

I have written a python Script to find out sentences containing Question Mark in a file.

```
f = open('Inline.txt',"r")    # open the file for reading
lines = f.readlines()         # read all the lines from it
for line in lines:
 if re.search("^[^\n]*\?[^\n]*(?:\n|$)",line):
    print(line)
f.close()
```

The Output is as expected.

```
And what exactly is it you're doing which is running ahead of -- or appearing torun ahead of expectations? That would my first question.

But I wondered can you talk a little bit more in terms of any signs in shift incustomer behavior or anything that can help us out as we think about next year? And I guess the defensibility of margins in that context as wellwould be helpful.Timo J.
```

Now I want to remove the above lines and any sentence less than 4 words. For that I have written the below script.

```
f = open('Inline.txt',"r")    
lines = f.readlines()         # read all the lines from it
f.close()                     # close the file

f = open('Inline.txt',"w")    


for line in lines:
  if len(line.split(' ')) >= 4 and "^[^\n]*\?[^\n]*(?:\n|$)" not in line:
      f.write(line)
f.close()
```

What am I doing wrong here? less than 4 words works fine but the sentences with question mark is still there.

Comment: You still need to use a regex, you cant just do `not in`

Comment: achieve your goal by using iterative method. first, use your regex to remove the question mark. second remove the 'less than 4 words' things..

Comment: Thank You. I have updated my code to use regex. for line in lines:
  if re.search("^[^\n]*\?[^\n]*(?:\n|$)",line):
    ""
  else:
    f.write(line)
f.close()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you suddenly change how to execute the regex from the first to the second code block. If you want to use regex and check if the pattern is in your file you have to use `re.search(pattern,text)` like you did in your first example. In your 2nd example you are looking if the text `^[^\n]*\?[^\n]*(?:\n|$)` is somewhere in your file and the probability for that is nil in a normal text.

Basically you only have to change:

```
if len(line.split(' ')) >= 4 and "^[^\n]*\?[^\n]*(?:\n|$)" not in line:
```

to:

```
if len(line.split(' ')) >= 4 and not re.search("^[^\n]*\?[^\n]*(?:\n|$)",line):
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how it could be achieved:

```
"""
remove lines containing: ^\n, ?, less than 4 words
"""

import re

with open('./Inline.txt', 'r') as rfd:
    for line in rfd:

        if line.startswith('\n'):
            continue

        words_pattern = re.compile(r'\w+')
        match = words_pattern.findall(line)
        if len(match) < 4:
            continue

        q_mark_pattern = re.compile(r'.+\?.+')
        if q_mark_pattern.match(line):
            continue

        print line
```

regular expressions are faster than parsing a string in python: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html. And it looks to be the right approach to solving this task because expression patterns are small. And also the above method is better in terms of space complexity, as it does not read the whole file into memory.